# What's the difference between module and algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am aware that algebra over a field has a bilinear multiplication, which is not a property of a module. Is that the only difference?

Comment: An algebra is a vector space over a field. A module is a vector space over a ring. Replace the ring in a module with a field to get a vector space. Add the multiplication with its properties to get the algebra.

Comment: @JohnDouma That depends on the author.  Many would use algebra and overring interchangably over a commutative ring with 1 (although "overring" is also different depending on author/context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether there are other differences depends on the context -- in particular what exactly the author means when they write "algebra". There is unfortunately not a firm agreement what it should mean.

*Sometimes* it is implicit in the word "algebra" that it's an algebra over a *field* in particular. But it is also common to allow the scalars to come from a general (commutative) ring.

In contrast, the word "module" never implies that the scalar ring is a field, because we have a specific term for that case: "vector space".

Additionally, *sometimes* when people say "algebra" without further qualification, they mean in particular an *associative algebra* where the multiplication is required to be associative in addition to being bilinear. At times they even mean a *unital associative algebra*, where there must also be an identity element for the multiplication.

This is akin to the ambiguity about whether a "ring" is required to be commutative, and/or have an identity element. One needs to check the definitions of the particular text one is reading.